# How do I chase dependency errors in nugets in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am getting the error: "Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=14.0" whenever I attempt to build the default "Blank App (Universal Windows)" app.

I know I have compiled UWP apps before, and is potentially a consequence of recently trying the VS2019 preview (now removed)

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling VS2019, VS2017, even installed 2015 and the blank UWP apps in each all come up with the same error.
I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling/repairing Windows 10 SDK's.
I've tried various versions of the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to no avail.  (The default is v6.2.10).

Can anyone explain how I can logically chase this error?  I'm assuming that it is failing to build the UniversalWindowsPlatform nuget - is this correct?  What is supposed to be installing the vclibs extension?  How can I see what is preventing it from being installed?

Comment: Have you tried edit the project's target version to other?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, Yes, I have tried the three latest versions of the Windows SDK 2004, 1903 and 1809...

Comment: Please check if you have installed C++ (v142) universal windows platform tool?

Comment: And please check if there is content in this path  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\`

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I don't have a Microsoft.VCLibs\14 directory - I've only got a Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop\14 directory.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT In VS2019 Setup I have the MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 checked.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225205/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-peter-carpenter).

Comment: Please install the package [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgadcFziRxGgYyz5cnw?e=loKeqB)and build your project again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No amount of repairing/installing VS2019, VS2017 or even VS2015, adding or removing options, (re)installing SDKs, (re)installing Visual C++ Runtime libraries made any difference.

what did eventually work was installing VS2019 on a new PC and then copying its entire "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs directory across.

If installing VS2019 installs this directory, I'm not sure why it doesn't fix it as part of reinstalling and/or repairing it!!  An opportunity for improvement in VS2019 repair perhaps?

Big thankyou to @NicoZhu-MSFT for all of your help!!